# Change dynamically validated_file_class in symfony 1.4

Tags: forms, symfony1, validation, symfony-1.4

I have this model:

```
Banner:
 columns:
  filename: string(255)
  url: string(255)
  position:
   type: enum
   values: [top, right]
   default: right
```

and this form:

```
class BannerForm extends BaseBannerForm
{
  public function configure()
  {
    $this->widgetSchema['filename'] = new sfWidgetFormInputFileEditable(array(
      'file_src' => $this->getObject()->getThumbURL(),
      'is_image' => true,
      'edit_mode' => $this->getObject()->exists()
    ));
    $validated_file_class = $this->getObject()->position === 'right' ? 'bannerRightValidatedFile' : 'bannerTopValidatedFile';
    $this->validatorSchema['filename'] = new sfValidatorFile(array(
      'path' => sfConfig::get('sf_upload_dir'),
      'mime_types' => 'web_images',
      'validated_file_class' => $validated_file_class',
      'required' => $this->getObject()->isNew()
    ));
  }
}
```

I use different validate classes because inside it i incapsulate thumbnail operations, and the sizes of banners depends on it position field.
The problem is that $validated_file_class is always bannerRightValidatedFile class.
How i can achieve this thing ?

Comment: as an alternate solution you can put the image resizing into the `preSave` or `postSave` method of the `Banner` class and leave the validator alone @kirugan

Comment: @1ed yes i can, but i think it leads to bad code

Comment: why do you think that? I think it is much cleaner than the validator hacks metioned below.

Comment: i prefer the way when all the same login in one place (in my case it is validation logic, and some specific callbacks), it might be difficult in future to refactor code style that you propose. Personally, i use preSave and postSave for things which related to the model itself.

Comment: I think it's not validation logic, just resizing a file based on the current state of a model object... but anyway if you want to put it in the form then you should change the validated file class just before processing the uploaded file. You can do that by overriding the `processValues` method or more better by adding a `updateFilenameColumn` method. I can post an answer how to do that if you are interested.

Comment: @1ed yes, please post

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can suggest 4 solutions which you can choose from:

**Option 1:**

You should add a update$fieldNameColumn method to the form class. In your case it should look like this:

```
// change validated file instance before calling save
protected function updateFilenameColumn($value)
{
  if ($value instanceof sfValidatedFile)
  {
    $class = 'right' == $this->getValue('position') ? 'bannerRightValidatedFile' : 'bannerTopValidatedFile';
    // this will not work as I thought at first time
    // $this->getValidator('filename')->setOption('validated_file_class', $class);

    $this->values['filename'] = new $class(
      $value->getOriginalName(),
      $value->getType(),
      $value->getTempName(),
      $value->getSize(),
      $value->getPath()
    );

    return $this->processUploadedFile('filename');
  }

  return $value;
}
```

I think it's kind of hacky.

**Option 2:**

You should add a doctrine hook method to the model:

```
/**
 * @param Doctrine_Event $event
 */
public function postSave($event)
{
  $record = $event->getInvoker();

  if (array_key_exists('filename', $record->getLastModified()))
  {
    // get the full path to the file
    $file = sfConfig::get('sf_upload_dir') . '/' . $record->getFilename();

    if (file_exists($file))
    {
      // resize the file e.g. with sfImageTransformPlugin
      $img = new sfImage($file);
      $img
        ->resize(100, 100)
        ->save();
    }
  }
}
```

This will work when creating records whitout a form e.g. when using fixtures.

**Option 3:**

Use the [`admin.save_object`](http://symfony.com/legacy/doc/reference/1_4/en/15-Events#chapter_15_sub_doctrine_admin_save_object) event.

```
public static function listenToAdminSaveObject(sfEvent $event)
{
  $record = $event['object'];

  if ($event['object'] instanceof Banner)
  {
    // use the same code as in the `postSave` example
  }
}
```

**Option 4:**

Use the [sfImageTransformExtraPlugin](http://www.symfony-project.org/plugins/sfImageTransformExtraPlugin)

It's kind of hard to setup and configure (and it's code is a mess :), but it makes possible to modify the size of the image whithout regenerating all the already resized ones.

Comment: Thank you for so much options, i will try it soon

Comment: sorry, i was busy to answer

Comment: No problem. Which option did you go with? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You could add a sfCallbackValidator as a post-validator, and set the property accordingly.

Pseudo code (I don't have the exact function signatures at hand).

```
public function configure() {
  // ...
  $this->mergePostValidator(new sfCallbackValidator(array('callback' => array($this, 'validateFile'))));
}

public function validateFile($values) {
   $realValidator = new sfValidatorFile(...);
   return $realValidator->clean($values['field']);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you can modify the call to the form class, you can do that:

```
$form = new BannerForm(array(), array('validated_file_class' => 'bannerRightValidatedFile');
$form2 = new BannerForm(array(), array('validated_file_class' => 'bannerTopValidatedFile');
```

And then in your form:

```
class BannerForm extends BaseBannerForm
{
  public function configure()
  {
    $this->widgetSchema['filename'] = new sfWidgetFormInputFileEditable(array(
      'file_src'  => $this->getObject()->getThumbURL(),
      'is_image'  => true,
      'edit_mode' => $this->getObject()->exists()
    ));

    $this->validatorSchema['filename'] = new sfValidatorFile(array(
      'path'                 => sfConfig::get('sf_upload_dir'),
      'mime_types'           => 'web_images',
      'validated_file_class' => $this->options['validated_file_class'],
      'required'             => $this->getObject()->isNew()
    ));
  }
}
```

**Edit:**

Since you are playing inside the admin gen, I think the best way is to use a postValidator like @Grad van Horck says.

Your validate class depend on an extra field. With a postvalidator, you can access any field inside the form. Then, you just need to create a little switch to handle the case for each position / validated class.

```
public function configure()
{
    // ...
    $this->mergePostValidator(new sfValidatorCallback(array('callback' => array($this, 'validateFile'))));
}

public function validateFile($validator, $values, $arguments)
{
    $default = array(
        'path'       => sfConfig::get('sf_upload_dir'),
        'mime_types' => 'web_images',
        'required'   => $this->getObject()->isNew()
    );

    switch ($values['position'] ) {
        case 'right':
            $validator =  new sfValidatorFile($default + array(
                'validated_file_class' => 'bannerRightValidatedFile',
            ));
            break;

        case 'top':
            $validator =  new sfValidatorFile($default + array(
                'validated_file_class' => 'bannerTopValidatedFile',
            ));

        default:
            # code...
            break;
    }

    $values['filename'] = $validator->clean($values['filename']);

    return $values;
}
```

Comment: Hm... i see, but i use it in admin area, so i should change some partial files, create action to handle request, look at some field and then create appropriate form. Maybe there is simple way ? I mean in case admin form

Comment: Hum I see, it's more complicated inside admin gen without modify too much files. I think the postValidator is a good solution, I'll update my answer.